Import dependencies or use quickstart command?
I'm somewhat new to Node, and I've been learning how to use Express, TypeORM, and I've recently discovered NestJS (which seems like it would be a great addition to my tools). I'm used to seeing in the quickstart guides for these frameworks a project scaffolding command like the following
NestJS
nest new project-name

TypeORM
npx typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres

and others.
Judging that it would be easier to add Express routing after having a TypeORM prepped project, I added routing to an existing TypeORM project rather than adding TypeORM features to an existing project. I figure I could probably add NestJS to my existing project, but NestJS seems to be a higher level framework, so maybe it would be less pain to start there and add existing code to a NestJS project.
Thoughts?
